# Google Analytics Custom Data Studio Field: Unknown dimension or metric ID: _ga____campaign_

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, regexp-replace

There is a slight difference in the account names in Google Ad Words and Google Analytics: AdWords will have a campaign called "*Brand_Campaign [Ex]" while the name in Google Analytics is "Brand_Campaign_Ex"

If I want to stitch these together, I need to replace all the symbols and convert the entire campaign name to lower case. I'm trying to create a new field in the Google Analytics data using this formula:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign,'_','')
```

But Google Data Studio returns an error message saying

```
Unknown dimension or metric ID: _ga____campaign_.
```

The campaign dimension is definitely in the table. The same formula works to create a new dimension, but I cannot join on dimensions created on the fly. I have been able to do this exact thing for the Google AdWords table, but the Analytics table is returning this strange error. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this applies here but I had a similar problem. My problem was that the columns in my postgresSQL database contained special characters like `-` or `/`. I know that one should never use such characters but anyways - changed that and reconnected the database and everything worked fine!

Hope this helps!